# React Native Expo - Sudden Error cannot find module 'babel-preset-react'

Tags: react-native, expo, babeljs

I have looked over so and other forums but havent been able to find any answer to my problem.

My react native expo app worked on ios simulator, I added a placeholder to a textinput tag and got an error when the app refreshed in the simulator. I pulled from my git repo to a version that worked minutes earlier.

Now I get this error message in the terminal.
node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react'
Require stack:

- /Users/ts/MobileApps/OurShoppingList/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
- /Users/ts/MobileApps/OurShoppingList/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/ts/MobileApps/OurShoppingList/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/ts/MobileApps/OurShoppingList/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js
- /Users/ts/MobileApps/OurShoppingList/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.flow.js
- /Users/tsm/MobileApps/OurShoppingList/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.js
- /Users/ts/MobileApps/OurShoppingList/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
- If you want to resolve "react", use "module:react"
- Did you mean "@babel/react"?

I have tried
npm install
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react

but it has not made any difference. My app is 99% complete so gutted to have an error suddenly appear this close to the end.

does anyone have any advice on how to resolve this issue?

Here is my babel.config.js file

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo', "react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
  };
};
```

I have also added @babel/preset-react to babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["@babel/preset-react", 'babel-preset-expo', "react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
  };
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "osl",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
    "expo": "~47.0.9",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.2.2",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```